# How I can convert Object to String in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a function in the model and I return it to a variable like the following

```
 $books = DB::select('select * from books where category_id = 2');
 return $books;
```

And Laravel Query Builder return an object.How I can convert it to the string from the controller? Have a function for that? Please let's me know.

Comment: Your question is similar to "How do I convert an Array to a String?" It doesn't really make sense. Can you expand on your question and provide some code?

Comment: I had updated my question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you get from this query

```
$books = DB::select('select * from books where category_id = 2');
```

If you do

```
var_dump($books);
```

You'll see that it's an array, not an object.

You need a big string with all your records? You can serialize it:

```
return serialize($books);
```

But you'll have to

```
unserialize($value);
```

to use it.

You need to use the values you get from that select? You can use `foreach()` on that array:

```
foreach($books as $book)
{
   echo $book['name'];
}
```

Or you can do your select differently:

```
$books = Book::where('category_id',2)->get();
```

And do your foreach using the object notation:

```
foreach($books as $book)
{
   echo $book->name;
}
```